# O que faz o for e o que faz os colchetes em um array?

Tags: java, array

Pedi ajuda em alguns fóruns em um jogo da velha programado em java, entendi a lógica, porém não sabia como aplicá-la (quais comandos usar, e como usar), e vi a utilização de Arrays. Após ver um código completo, compreendi tudo, exceto por uma parte, essa parte aqui:

```
public boolean vitoria (int x){
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
            if(mat[i][0] == x && mat [i][1] == x && mat [i][2] == x){
                return true;
            }
            if(mat[0][i] == x && mat [1][i] == x && mat [2][i] == x){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(mat[0][0] == x && mat [1][1] == x && mat [2][2] == x){
            return true;
        }
        if(mat[0][2] == x && mat[1][1] == x && mat [2][0] == x){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

A minha dúvida é: O que significa `(int = 0;i <mat.lenght; i++)`, e o que significa cada linha, como por exemplo

```
if(mat[i][0] == x && mat [i][1] == x && mat [i][2] == x){
                    return true;
                }
```

O que significa os colchetes? e o que estão fazendo (qual função)? Lembrando que neste jogo da velha, o mat é a variável `int` que marca a posição que cada jogador jogou. Aqui vai o código completo caso seja necessário:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Jogo extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JButton b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9;
    int qtde;//verifica quantidade de jogadas da partida
    int jogador;// verifica o jogador da vez, sendo 1 = X e 2 = 0
    int mat[][] = new int [3][3];//marca a posição que cada jogador jogou
    JButton b[] = new JButton[9];//mapeia os botões
    String ganhador;//armazena nome do vencedor
    String jogador1;//armazena nome do jogador 1
    String jogador2;// armazena nome do jogador 2

    public Jogo() {
        setTitle("Jogo da Velha");
        setBounds(190,100,300,400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(197,197,197));
        setLayout(null);

        JMenuBar mBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu opcoes = new JMenu("Opções");
        JMenuItem nJogo = new JMenuItem("Novo Jogo");

        JMenuItem sair = new JMenuItem("Sair");

        mBar.add(opcoes);
        mBar.add(sair);
        opcoes.add(nJogo);

        setJMenuBar(mBar);

        b1 = new JButton();
        b1.setBounds(25,50,60,70);
        this.add(b1);

        b2 = new JButton();
        b2.setBounds(115,50,60,70);
        this.add(b2);

        b3 = new JButton();
        b3.setBounds(205,50,60,70);
        this.add(b3);

        b4 = new JButton();
        b4.setBounds(25,140,60,70);
        this.add(b4);

        b5 = new JButton();
        b5.setBounds(115,140,60,70);
        this.add(b5);

        b6 = new JButton();
        b6.setBounds(205,140,60,70);
        this.add(b6);

        b7 = new JButton();
        b7.setBounds(25,230,60,70);
        this.add(b7);

        b8 = new JButton();
        b8.setBounds(115,230,60,70);
        this.add(b8);

        b9 = new JButton();
        b9.setBounds(205,230,60,70);
        this.add(b9);

        qtde = 1;
        jogador = 1;

        b[0] = b1;
        b[1] = b2;
        b[2] = b3;
        b[3] = b4;
        b[4] = b5;
        b[5] = b6;
        b[6] = b7;
        b[7] = b8;
        b[8] = b9;

        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b1,0,0);
            }
        });
        b2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b2,0,1);
            }
        });
        b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b3,0,2);
            }
        });
        b4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b4,1,0);
            }
        });
        b5.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b5,1,1);
            }
        });
        b6.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b6,1,2);
            }
        });
        b7.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b7,2,0);
            }
        });
        b8.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b8,2,1);
            }
        });
        b9.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                jogada(b9,2,2);
            }
        });
        nJogo.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
                for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
                        b[i].setEnabled(true);
                        b[i].setText("");
                    }
                    for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++){
                        for(int y = 0; y <3; y++){
                            mat[x][y] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    jogador = 1;
                    jogador1="";
                    jogador2="";
                    ganhador="";
                }

        });

    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        new Jogo().setVisible(true);
    }
    public void jogada (JButton b, int x, int y){
        b.setEnabled(false);
        if(jogador == 1){
            mat[x][y] = 1;
            b.setText("X");
            jogador = 2;
            ganhador = jogador1;
            checarjogada(1);
        } else {
            if(jogador == 2){
                mat[x][y] = 2;
                b.setText("O");
                jogador = 1;
                ganhador = jogador2;
                checarjogada(2);
            }
            qtde++;
        }
    }
    public void checarjogada(int x){
        if(vitoria (x) == true){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Jogador:"+ganhador+"Venceu!","Vitória!",1);
            fimdojogo();
        }
    }
    public boolean vitoria (int x){
        for (int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++){
            if(mat[i][0] == x && mat [i][1] == x && mat [i][2] == x){
                return true;
            }
            if(mat[0][i] == x && mat [1][i] == x && mat [2][i] == x){
                return true;
            }
        }
        if(mat[0][0] == x && mat [1][1] == x && mat [2][2] == x){
            return true;
        }
        if(mat[0][2] == x && mat[1][1] == x && mat [2][0] == x){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    public void fimdojogo(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
            b[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tive que publicar minha resposta com dados faltando pois deu bug aqui na página, aguarde que editarei a resposta com os dados correto.

Comment: Estou no aguardo, porém não se preocupe, pois já me ajudou a compreender quase que completamente ! Agradeço desde já pela ajuda !

Comment: pronto finalizei a resposta, espero ter ajudado a compreender a sua dúvida, caso minha resposta serviu para sanar sua dúvida não esqueça de dar um voto positivo e marcá-la como resposta aceita de baixo do voto.

Comment: Sem problemas !

Comment: o que são colchetes?

Comment: Olá @JorgeB., as "colchetes" ditas por mim seriam os arrays ! Isso [] são colchetes!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Você sabe o que significa for?

For é uma estrutura de ***repetição***, ótima para iterar por `arrays` e `listas`.

```
for (int i = 0; i <mat.lenght; i++)
```

Esta linha acima significa:

Para (for) uma variável `i` do tipo `inteiro (int)` com valor inicial igual `0`, repita todo o código que estiver dentro do bloco do `for` (Ou seja, o bloco que está entre as chaves `{}` depois do for.
Repita até quando? Repita até `i` ser menor que o tamanho do array bidimensional `mat`; Durante cada repetição incremente `i` em mais 1.

Como você pode ver no seu for temos três declarações separados por `;`. Veja:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < mat.length; i++ ) {
    O que está dentro dessas chaves será repetido.
}
```

Conseguiu ver os `;` na declaração do for?

Então a primeira parte significa isto:

1. Para (for) uma variável `i` do tipo `inteiro (int)` com valor inicial igual `0`
2. Repita todo o código que estiver dentro do bloco do `for` (Ou seja, o bloco que está entre as chaves `{}` depois do for.
3. Repita até quando? Repita até `i` ser menor que o tamanho do array bidimensional `mat`;
4. Durante cada repetição incremente `i` em mais 1.

Deu para entender? Tentei não complicar o máximo possível, espero ter ajudado.

Quanto ao uso de colchetes de array, seja unidimensional ou bidimensional, pense da seguinte forma:

```
int[] mat = new int [3];
```

O array mat tem um tamanho de 3 e, como temos um colchete em sua declaração, ele é um array unidimensional e de inteiros.
Imagine mat como três copos vazios. Você tem o copo 0, 1, 2 (Sempre começando do 0, mas não deixam de ser três copos).
Se você quiser adicionar qualquer número e qualquer que seja o copo, você tem que dizer em qual copo você quer adicionar o número assim:

```
mat[0] = 20; // Isso significa que o primeiro copo, representado pela POSIÇÃO 0, armazenará o elemento (número) 20.
```

E para o segundo copo?

```
mat[1] = 20; // Isso significa que o segundo copo, representado pela POSIÇÃO 1, armazenará o elemento (número) 20.
```

E assim por diante.

Agora vamos para o array BIDIMENSIONAL.

```
int mat[][] = new int [3][3];//marca a posição que cada jogador jogou
```

Como temos dois colchetes significa que o array é bidimensional.
`[3]` Temos um array que pode armazenar 3 elementos. Porém cada elemento desse na verdade, contém um outro array que aí sim pode armazenar 3 elementos, por isso `[3][3]`.

```
[Posição 0 / Elemento 1], [Posição 1 / Elemento 2], [Posição 0 / Elemento 3]
```

Só que ao invés de poder armazenar um elemento dentro de cada posição, você tem um array dentro de cada posição que pode armazenar três elementos. Dentro de Posição 0, você pode armazenar Elemento 1, Elemento 2, Elemento 3 assim:

```
mat[0][0] = 20; Na primeira posição do array que está dentro da posição 0.
mat[0][1] = 30; Na segunda posição do array que está dentro da posição 0.
mat[0][2] = 30; Na terceira posição do array que está dentro da posição 0.
```

Pronto finalizamos o primeiro array que estava dentro da posição 0. Adicionamos somente 3 elementos nessa array porque...Lembra? [3][3] (Este segundo 3).

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, não sabe como ajudou, espero poder ajudar um dia também !

Comment: @GabrielOzzy de nada. Uma mão lava a outra. E quanto mais ajudamos, mais aprendemos.